# Only members can submit this form php

Tags: php

New to php.  I have a form that is only for members to submit.  What php code do I need for the form to check that the email address on the form is found my members database and then its okay to submit the form?

If email address is not in the members database then I want to echo "Only members can submit this form."  What php code do I need to connect to database in the form and do the check so I don't get forms submitted from non members?
Thanks

Comment: food for thought: what is to stop someone who isn't registered from submitting a registered member's email? It is not very secure to use an email address field for authentication.

Answer (score 1):

At the top of your php file you could do something like this:

```
 if(isset($_POST['email'])) {
    mysql_connect("hostname","username","password");
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = '".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email'])."'");
    if($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
       // found email
    } else {
       // email wasn't found
    }
  }
```

Of course you would need to replace the `hostname`, `username` and `password` to correct values, also you should change the `users` and `email` in the select query to the name of your table and field.

Here is a dummy form:

```
 <form method="POST" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']; ?>">
    <input type="text" name="email" />
    <input type="submit" value="Send" />
 </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to study [Mysql query](http://sk.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) and other mysql functions. The code would basically look like:

```
$c = mysql_connect( ...);
mysql_select_db( 'database', $c);
$q = mysql_query( "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users WHERE email = '" . 
    mysql_real_escape_string( $_POST['email'],$c) . "'");
$row = mysql_fetch_row( $q);
if( $row[0]){
    echo "Thanks for submitting...";
} else {
    echo "Only members...";
}
```

This is only brief example which is far from perfection but I think it's good place for you to start.

Answer (score -1):

If someone is a registered member that implies you're very likely using a $_SESSION['id_member'] variable.

This will set the cookie's name that can be seen by the client to 'member'...

```
if (!headers_sent() && !isset($_SESSION))
{
 session_name('member');
}
```

...then when a user authenticates assign a session variable and their permission...

```
 $_SESSION['member_id'] = $mysql_row['id'];
 $_SESSION['member_status'] = $mysql_row['id'];
```

Here is a status hierarchy that you might use or change but it should be a good point of reference...

10 - Super Admin (only you)

9 - Admin// mid-level admin

8 - Assistant//restrictive admin

7 - Moderator//Don't give this status to any jerks

6 - Premium Member//they gave you money!

5 - Registered Member//normal account status

4 - Frozen Account//not banned but did something wrong, will "thaw"

3 - Unverified Email Address//registered but did not verify email

2 - Unregistered Visitor//human

1 - Good Bots

0 - Banned

Generally first determine how to catch the form...

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='GET')
{

}
else if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST')
{
 if (isset($_POST['submit_button_name_value'])) {blog_post_ajax_comment();}
}
```

I add the name="value" attribute/value to submit buttons, why? Have two submit options (preview and publish in example) you may want to have the server trigger one function or the other, VERY simple and valid (X)HTML.

You should check if the variable isset (keep permissions in mind).

Then check if their user permissions are adequate, you can use a simple integer to represent this.

Then wrap the isset and permission if statements around two things, one the form and secondly make sure you use these conditions when PROCESSING the form.

I always test against things to reject and throwing in database query error handling to give you a little extra boost...

```
//function module_method_ajax_purpose()
function blog_post_ajax_comment()
{
 if (!isset($_SESSION['member'])) {http_report('403',__FUNCTION__,'Error: you must be signed in to do that.');}
 else if ($_SESSION['member_status']<=4) {http_report('403',__FUNCTION__,'Error: permission denied; your account has been flagged for abuse.');}
 else if (flood_control($datetime,'60')!=1) {http_report('403',__FUNCTION__,'Error: you can only post a comment once every X seconds.');}
 else if (!isset($_POST['post_form_name_1']) || !isset($_POST['post_form_name_2'])) {http_report('403',__FUNCTION__,'Error: permission denied.');}
 else
 {
  // NOW process
  $query1 = "SELECT * FROM table";
  $result1 = mysql_query($query1);

  if ($result1)
  {
   //successful, increment query number for further queries
  }
  else {mysql_error_report($query1,mysql_error(),__FUNCTION__);}
 }
```

Error reporting is VERY powerful, use it for HTTP, JavaScript, PHP and MySQL. You could also benefit from my answer about real-time log reading here: [jQueryUI tabs and Firefox: getBBox broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8840004/firefox-getbbox-broken-in-v9/8840560#8840560)